# Group variables in ggplot2 (geom_col)

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I want to plot variables from a dataframe into different groups, but cannot figure out how to do this.

Mock data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(animal=c("cat1","cat2","mouse1","mouse2","dog1","dog2"),size=c(3,4,1,2,6,7))
plot<-ggplot(df)+geom_col(mapping=aes(x=animal,y=size))
plot
```

[image: current output]

My wanted output should look like this:

[image: wanted output]

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest next approach. You have to create a group and then use facets. Most of these tricks I learnt from @AllanCameron that has great answer for problems of this style.Next the code that can do that:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df<-data.frame(animal=c("cat1","cat2","mouse1","mouse2","dog1","dog2"),
               size=c(3,4,1,2,6,7),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Create group
df$Group <- gsub('\\d+','',df$animal)
#Now plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=animal,y=size))+
  geom_col()+
  facet_wrap(.~Group,scales = 'free', strip.position = "bottom")+
  theme(strip.placement  = "outside",
        panel.spacing    = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text       = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution with the facets! Maybe you could use `scales = "free_x"` for better comparability, but I think this is also a bit a personal choice

Comment: @starja I absolutely agree with you. It depends of personal choice. Also, your answer is nice :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Duck. I would have to rescale the axes, but this could work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell ggplot to which group an animal belongs to; then you can use the group argument on the x-axis and use the `fill` argument to further distinguish between the different animals. `position = "dodge"` leads to the bars showing up next to each other.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(animal = c("cat1","cat2","mouse1","mouse2","dog1","dog2"),
                 size=c(3,4,1,2,6,7),
                 group = c("cat", "cat", "mouse", "mouse", "dog", "dog"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = size, fill = animal)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a bunch Starja! This is exactly the solution I was looking for. I saw in the vignette that there was a group argument, but coundn't figure out how it was working.

Comment: Glad to help! If you don't want the animals to have different colours, you can use `group` instead of `fill`; and with `geom_col(width = 0.8, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))` you can tweak the spacing