# Grouping bar chart by filtered rows (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouped-bar-chart

I want to display time series data on a grouped bar chart. I filtered the two variables from one column (x, y). Unfortunately I can't figure out how to display them grouped.

Using the code below will stack the bars:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

target <- c("x", "y")
filtered_dat <- filter(dat, column %in% target)

ggplot(filtered_dat, aes(year, column)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", width = 0.7) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = column), colour = "white")
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: A likely dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63551040/3358272

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group `aes()` solves the problem. Therefore I had to group them with the  `group = column` code.